# Mutating list in python

Tags: python, list, mutation

I want to define a function which can mutate the inputted list by adding 1's([1,1,1,...]) in to it.
But, I don't want to use loops to perform this simple operation.

```
# input - a list (empty list)
#       - number of elements to initialize
# output- None
#       - But it will have to mutate the inputted (list)
def initialize_one(empty_lis, n):
    # Do nothing if e_lis is a non-empty list
    if len(empty_lis) is not 0:
        return
    else:
        temp = [1] * n
        # empty_lis = temp will not mutate
        # And I don't want to use loops to append
        # because if n = 100,000
        # it will have to loop for 100,000 times


lis = []
n = 10
initialize_one(lis, n)

print lis
# expected output
# >>>[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Please don't use `is` when checking equality

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need such a function? `empty_lis = [1] * 100` is more readable and shorter.

Comment: @Blender I also want to define a function for union which accepts two list and the function will be mutating the first list. like 
    a = list(set(a) | set(b))

Comment: @BalaKrishnan: So why don't you use sets?

Comment: @Blender Actually I don't know how to mutate a list but now I understood it from the answer of jamyalk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def initialize_one(seq, n):
    if not seq:
        seq[:] = [1] * n
```